# access command defined in nested user controls wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I have a `MainWindow` derived from `Window` class. That window has a `ContentControl` that is used to host user `UserControl` objects in it. I am trying to create a button that will access a `Command` that was defined in that nested `UserControl`. The only trick is that my user control actually has more user controls nested in it too, and I am actually going for the grand-child command rather than just a child. Something like this:

Main Window:

```
<metro:MetroWindow  x:Class="GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Wpf.MainWindow"
                    x:Name="win"
                    xmlns:metro="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                    xmlns:pmModel="clr-namespace:GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Management.ParametersManagerWPF.ViewModel"
                    xmlns:pmLocal="clr-namespace:GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Management.ParametersManagerWPF"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Wpf"
                    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="400" Width="600" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" 
                    Title="{Binding WindowTitle, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='GrimshawDT'}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" BorderThickness="1"
                    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowTransitionsEnabled="False">
    <metro:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pmModel:pmViewModel}">
                <pmLocal:pmMain />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </metro:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height = "100" />
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentControl x:Name="MainContentControl" Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnOK" Content="OK" Margin="0,0,211,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Command="{Binding pmModel:pmViewModel.ApplyCommand, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" metro:ButtonHelper.CornerRadius="0" metro:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing="Normal" BorderThickness="1" metro:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True"/>
    </Grid>
</metro:MetroWindow>
```

Control that is nested into the MainWindow:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Management.ParametersManagerWPF.pmMain"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Management.ParametersManagerWPF" 
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Management.ParametersManagerWPF.ViewModel"
             xmlns:Custom="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:pmSetParamToValueViewModel}">
                <local:pmSetParamToValueView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:pmCopyParamToParamViewModel}">
                <local:pmCopyParamToParamView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:pmCopyParamToParamSliceViewModel}">
                <local:pmCopyParamToParamSliceView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:pmCombineTwoSlicesViewModel}">
                <local:pmCombineTwoSlicesView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbType" Margin="0,26,0,0" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding PageNames}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedVMIndex}" Custom:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Parameter Manager Functionality"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" Margin="0,57,0,0"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Select Functionality:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This in turn has more nested controls like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Management.ParametersManagerWPF.pmSetParamToValueView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Management.ParametersManagerWPF"
             xmlns:Custom="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="600" d:DesignHeight="200">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbCategories" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}" Custom:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Category" Margin="0,26,0,0"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbSourceParam" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,57,0,0" Width="180" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParameter}" Custom:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Source Parameter"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbParamValue" Margin="185,57,0,0" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Custom:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Parameter Value"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Define Parameters:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now, when a OK button is hit in the main window, I want this second nested control to execute a `ApplyCommand`. This is my second user control's view model:

```
namespace GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Management.ParametersManagerWPF.ViewModel
{
    public class pmSetParamToValueViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public pmModel model;
        public ObservableCollection<CategoryWrapper> Categories { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand ApplyCommand { get; private set; }

        public pmSetParamToValueViewModel(Document doc)
        {
            this.model = new pmModel(doc);
            this.Categories = model.CollectCategories();
            SelectedCategory = Categories[0];
            this.ApplyCommand = new RelayCommand(this.Apply);
        }

        // logic for apply button
        private void Apply()
        {
            model.Apply(SelectedCategory.ID, SelectedParameter, null, null, Value, null, null, null, "Apply");
        }

        // logic for storing parameter value
        private string _value;
        public string Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                if (_value == value) return;

                _value = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Value);
            }
        }

        // storage for source parameters
        private ObservableCollection<ParameterWrapper> _parameters;
        public ObservableCollection<ParameterWrapper> Parameters
        {
            get { return _parameters; }
            set
            {
                if (_parameters == value) return;

                _parameters = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Parameters);
                if (Parameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    SelectedParameter = Parameters[0];
                }
            }
        }

        // logic for selected category
        private CategoryWrapper _selectedCategory;
        public CategoryWrapper SelectedCategory
        {
            get { return _selectedCategory; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedCategory == value) return;

                _selectedCategory = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedCategory);
                Parameters = model.CollectParameters(SelectedCategory.ID, new string[] { "String", "Double", "Integer" });
            }
        }

        // logic for selected source parameter
        private ParameterWrapper _selectedParameter;
        public ParameterWrapper SelectedParameter
        {
            get { return _selectedParameter; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedParameter == value) return;

                _selectedParameter = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedParameter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how to set up the OK button in the Main Window to be able to access the command that was defined in nested user control. Alternatively is there a way to set up a OK button to retrieve current status of the given nested user control so that I can retrieve their properties and use these as an argument for my `ApplyCommand`?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you have references to the child viewmodels already in your main viewmodel, so I believe this should work:

```
<Button x:Name="btnOK" Content="OK" Margin="0,0,211,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Command="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel.CurrentPageViewModel.ApplyCommand}" Grid.Row="1" metro:ButtonHelper.CornerRadius="0" metro:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing="Normal" BorderThickness="1" metro:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True"/>
```

Comment: Yes, this works great. Thank you. I will award you the bounty. I did however realized that what I asked for is not what I really want to do. I am not always going to have a user control nested inside another user control. Sometimes (most times) I will just have a single user control. To handle both cases i would like to bind that button like so `Binding CurrentPageViewModel.ApplyCommand` then put the `ApplyCommand` and `Apply` method inside the main user control and if possible go from there. Is there a way to access my nested controls from code in the `ViewModel`?

Comment: Problem is that the `CurrentPageViewModel` is a base class `ViewModelBase` and doesn't allow me to access methods inside of it. Since the current page can be any of the view models I would need to cast it into a specific one selected before I get access to its methods. :-( I could implement my own base view model and add Apply Method to it so that it was always available. Is that a way to go?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand, so apologies if this doesn't work in your scenario, but perhaps you could bind your button to CurrentPageViewModel.ApplyCommand as you have suggested, but with something along the lines of this:

    if (this.CurrentPageViewModel != null)
{
this.CurrentPageViewModel.ApplyCommand.Execute()
}
else
{
this.Apply();
}

Comment: I just ended up extending the `ViewModelBase` class and added `ApplyCommand` to it so that I had access to it from the base level. It works for me. Thanks for all the comments.